# Why is ajax working on one server and not the next?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have some script that works on my dev server but not on my staging server:

```
    add_action('wp_head','get_gz_info',30);
    function get_gz_info(){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var modal = {action:'modal_action'};
                var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            $.post(ajaxurl,modal,function(data){
                $('body').append(data);
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

the php is roughly:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_modal_action', 'set_modal');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_modal_action', 'set_modal');
    function set_modal() {
...
}
```

Everything works fine on my dev side but the staging side the javascript is placed in the header (just like the dev) but it won't run the "ajax part". Could it be that the staging side requires a username/password to access it?

I've attempted it with and without the https and get the same results.

According to the inspect this is being set as the ajaxurl, "...mysite.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" so the ajaxurl is being implemented. The odd issue is it works as is on one server but not the next.

----- EDIT -----
The html shows this as the js in the head (after jquery loads)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var modal = {action:'modal_action'};
                var ajaxurl = '...mysite.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
            $.post(ajaxurl,modal,function(data){
                $('body').append(data);
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML (and not the PHP) code as the browser receives it.

Comment: I've added what the output is to the browser in the head

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's javascript console?

Comment: No, I can even alert from the script except for anything inside the $.post. Thing is, it works as is on one server but not the next.

Comment: Are you sure `admin-ajax.php` is returning a status 200 response?

Comment: Good idea. I tested and it's not seeing the file. Of course I run the same code on my dev server and it sees the admin-ajax file just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who setup the staging server placed and .htaccess in the admin side that prevented the site from accessing files in the wp-admin area.